# Javascript: requestIdleCallback with timeout is always fired immediately

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout, idle-processing, requestidlecallback

I want to send analytics data to server at low priority. My function is:

```
const schedule_serversync = function (deadline) {
    if (deadline.timeRemaining() > 0) {
        server_sync(); //async ajax call of approx few ms duration
    }
    requestIdleCallback(schedule_serversync, { timeout: 60000 });
}
```

As soon as I call `requestIdleCallback(schedule_serversync, { timeout: 60000 });` from `onload`, `schedule_serversync` is called immediately and the requests go into infinite tight loop. **This happens even if the window is not idle (I'm clicking, moving mouse etc, but the callbacks continue).**

I know I can break the tight loop using `setTimeout` while rescheduling `requestIdleCallback`.

**My question is** - shouldn't `schedule_serversync` be called only when browser is idle with max delay of 60 seconds? What defines idle here? I was expecting it to be fired when user moves to some other browser tab or window. Is there a way I can set minimum delay (other than using `setTimeout` of my own)?

Comment: You're not checking the `didTimeout` flag on the deadline object.

Comment: You might also want to look into `sendBeacon`, it seems like it might be closer to what you want.

Comment: Also "idle" means "not running any event loops". If you're sitting there just staring at the page, the browser is idle.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how the timeout is used. It doesn't mean "idle for 60 seconds". It means "queue the function in 60 seconds even if we've never been idle". Your code will run in a tight loop whenever the browser is idle.

Comment: What you might want to do is use `setInterval()` to periodically call `requestIdleCallback()`.